# How to keep track of when my OpenVPN connection is up (systemd)

Tags: openvpn, systemd, kde-plasma-5

I'm using the service openvpn-client@.service to connect to my VPN. When I start my computer it takes a little while for it to connect. I would like to see a desktop notification when the connection is established. Preferably a native KDE notification.

It would also be good if I could get a notification if the connection fails.

I know NetworkManager will give me notification but I would like to use systemd.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `notify-send` to send a notification.

A simple way to get this to work, therefore would be to poll `systemctl status` repeatedly from a bash script and start that script in the background in your `.profile`.

It's not elegant, but it will take you <5 minutes to write and will work fine.

Edit: The more systemctl-y way to do it would be to write a unit that depends on your openvpn-client service and have it send a message on success. You could use a systemctl timer that gets cancelled by that first unit to send a failure message.

But I don't really see the point. You'd have to faff with your environment variables and it'll be no more readable or reliable :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I used the first method it seems there would either be some delay before I get the message or I would have to poll very often. The second method seems more like what I want but I noticed a somewhat different method I might be able to use. There is a .conf file for my VPN that OpenVPN uses. I can make it call scripts when the VPN goes up or down. I made it run notify-send like you recommended but because OpenVPN is run as root I don't see the message. Do you know how to get around this? I also tried putting `wall -n "VPN is up"` in there but all terminals get it.

Comment: You're welcome. You can use `sudo -u <your user> notify-send`. You'll also need to set the necessary environment variables (DBUS socket, if I recall correctly). You can dump all your environment variables to a temp file at startup with `export -p > filename` and load them with `source filename`. If that works you can experiment with removing some of the variables until you have a minimum set.

If you use multiple X displays the easiest approach is to just message them all.

Comment: You can edit the systemctl script to call something on success or failure, too, if you'd rather.

Comment: To do it with systemctl: use OnFailure= for reporting failure and a second service that wants openvpn-client@ for reporing success.